# Microsoft Office 2011 Mac - Removing individual components

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2011

I've installed 2011 fully but now need to remove Office, Messenger and maybe some other components. How can I do it in correct way, so it will clean up all related data.

Comment: What related data are you concerned about?

Comment: Preferences, temporary files, some data that may not be removed by just drag&dropping icon to trash. Usually from Library.

Comment: Not really a mac person, so not sure, but I belive that all that will be wiped with a regular drag to trash.

Comment: @soandos Very unlikely. It's a multi-user system. User data is not stored with the application.

Comment: Sorry, didnt realize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2398768) from Microsoft's knowledge base. Check on the linked page for up to date instructions, but to summarize: Delete the following (`*` being a wildcard):

- `/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.*`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office 2011` or `~/Library/Preferences/Microsoft/Office 2011`
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist`
- `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper`
- `/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.licensing.plist`
- `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/` (This will also remove Silverlight)
- `/Library/Receipts/Office2011_*`
- `/private/var/db/receipts/com.microsoft.office*`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/`
- `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/`
- `~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/`

Restart afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

A tool like [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) will do much of this cleanup for you.